# android send action_call from broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, call, forward

i want to forward all phone calls after receive a sms , so i have to using broadcastreceiver to listen incoming sms , this is my code :

```
public class SMSListiner extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("*21*02164371348#")));
        callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(callIntent);
    }}
```

and this is manifest

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.arash.SMSListiner">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".SMSListiner">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

</manifest>
```

`

call is sent but i have an error :
"call forwarding , connection problem or invalid MMI Code"

but when i try this code to send action_call in activity i have no problem and it work correctly ,
any idea ?

Comment: Are you using a phone or an emulator ?

Comment: I Using phone , sony xperia z.